# Arithmetic on lists within lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to take a nested list and replace each sub-list with an arithmetic operation on its elements. For example:
a={{1,3},{2,2},{2,3}}. I want to get {4,4,5}.
I can do it by: f{x_,y_}=x+y and then Map[f,a] but I suspect that there has to be an easier way by applying rules or similar.

Comment: `Map` is the straightforward way to go. You can use pure functions instead of defining `f[x, y]`. In this particular case, `Plus @@@ a` works. In pure functions: `(#1 + #2) & @@@ a`.

Comment: `Total` with a level spec is designed for this purpose ..as per Carls answer

Answer (score 2):

For your example you can use [`Total`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total):

```
a = {{1,3},{2,2},{2,3}};

Total[a, {2}]
```

> {4, 4, 5}

Another possibility is to use [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot):

```
a . {1,1}
```

> {4, 4, 5}